# Where does -ι- come from in derivatives of ἅλς (ἁλιάετος, ἁλιαής, ἁλιανθής)?

Tags: greek, etymology

Many compounds or derivatives of the Greek word ἅλς *hals* "salt, sea" seem to be built on the form ἁλι- *hali-*: ἁλιά(ι)ετος "sea-eagle", ἁλιαής "blowing seaward", ἁλιανθής "sea-blooming" (I saw some others as well).

I'm not sure where the -ι- comes from: since ἅλς seems to have an inflectional stem ending in the consonant λ /l/, I would expect instead to see "*ἁλά(ι)ετος, *ἁλαής, *ἁλανθής".

Is ἁλι- derived from the dative singular form ἁλί, or is there some other source of the -ι-? Or is it different for different words?

Answer (score 4):

Beekes suggests (somewhat cryptically) that the compounding stem hali- is by analogy to i-stem nouns. Another possibility is that hali is an old locative, giving us compounds with inflected vorderglied.

Comment: Chantraine thinks it may actually preserve an old neuter i-stem, and gives some comparanda, e.g. Old Latin *sale*.